# azure app service reading custom environment variables from web.debug.config not configuration menu variables

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have an application, for which I'm trying to read environment variables from the Azure configuration menu. As such:

[image]

Then some code to read environment variables:

```
        public static string GetPathString() 
        {
          string targetEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TARGET_ENVIRONMENT");
          if (targetEnv.Equals(Environments.Dev))
          {
            return "/RCHHRATool/";
          }
          else if (targetEnv.Equals(Environments.Azure))
          {
            return "/";
          }
          return "INVALID ENVIRONMENT SET IN ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES";
        }
```

However, what I'm finding is, the values being read into the code when deployed to Azure are still from web.debug.config, which presumably it shouldn't even be looking at considering it should be in release mode in the app service.

How do I read custom environment variables from the app service configuration?

Answer (score 2):

- The Azure environment variables are set from `web.config` or `appsettings.json` by default.
- If we want to override the values, we need to add them in Azure Configuration => App settings.
- The key name of the `AppSetting` must be same in both Development(local) and Azure App Settings.

In `Azure AppSettings`

[image]

***My `Web.config`***

```cs
<appSettings>
      <add key="TARGET_ENVIRONMENT" value="TARGET_ENVIRONMENT Development" /> 
  </appSettings>
```

***HomeController***

```cs
 public static string GetPathString()
        {
            var appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            var targetEnv = appsettings["TARGET_ENVIRONMENT"];            
            return targetEnv;
        }
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var EnvVariable = GetPathString();
            ViewBag.EnvVariable = EnvVariable;      
            return View();
        }
```

***Output***

[image]

Comment: Is this solution for .net core? Or asp.net 4?

Comment: The given solution is for ASP. Net 4 MVC.

Comment: The only problem with your answer is this: "value="TARGET_ENVIRONMENT Development"

It should just read as the intended value, not as also the variable name.